# How to convert a Laravel-5.4 function as unit testing code

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.4

How can I convert this Laravel-5.4 function as unit testing code:

```
public function addQtCart($id)
{
    $item = Cart::get($id);

    $products = MarketProduct::find($item->id);

    $available_quantity = $products->product->available_quantity;

    // Checking cart quantity with available item quantity in DB
    if($item->qty < $available_quantity){
      Cart::update($id, $item->qty + 1);
      Session::flash('alert-success', 'Quantity added to the cart!');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
    else{
        Session::flash('alert-danger', 'Product quantity is not available!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Please do not mention the documentation link, its bit complicated for me to understand the **"foo" and "bar"** examples as I am new in testing section.

N.B. Cart:: is a LaravelShoppingcart package.

Comment: Are you wondering how to make this particular function testable?

Comment: @Nick actually need to know the whole testing code of this function, after understanding this part I will apply it to all of my functions.

Comment: I don't think you need to change your function for testing purposes. It can be tested just like it is right now.

Comment: @Camilo are you telling me to put all the codes in the phpunit testing section? If I do it like that then I have to write same code over and over again. I am asking for phpunit test code for this function. this code already has been tested in GUI and running cool.